# Hide group on filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My REST API is returning grouped data,

```
{
  "Homer Simpson": [
    {
      "name": "First article",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "name": "Second article",
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "Marge Simpson": [
    {
      "name": "Third article"
      "type": "text
    }
  ]
}
```

Articles can be filtered:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Quicksearch" ng-model="quicksearch">
...
<div class="article-group" ng-repeat="(author, articles) in articles">
  <h3>{{author}} ({{filtered.length}})</h3>
  <div class="article" ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { name: quicksearch } as filtered">
```

The important thing here is the `({{filtered.length}})`. After applying a filter by typing something into the quicksearch input the length changes. Everything works fine, but I'd like hide "empty" authors; if you type in "third" you should no longer see Homer Simpson.

Tried `ng-if="filtered.length > 0"` on the `article-group` div, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put `ng-show="filtered.length"` on `.article-group` container:

```
<div class="article-group" ng-show="filtered.length" ng-repeat="(author, articles) in articles">
  <h3>{{author}} ({{filtered.length}})</h3>
  <div class="article" ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { name: quicksearch } as filtered">
    <pre>{{ article | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!